# Getting Json data from the controller to a view using razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, razor

I need to get the json data from the function in the controller:
I know there is many ways,
 I am trying one of them but right to now its not working

```
    private UserViewModel GetUsers()
    {
        UserViewModel vm = new UserViewModel();
        if (Session["Data"] == null)
        {
            var json = @"{
                  '$id': '1',
                  'Users': [

                    {
                      '$id': '7',
                      'RoleCode': 3,
                      'RoleDescription': 'משתמש רגיל',
                      'Id': '336387519',
                      'Username': 'ראובן',
                      'Email': 'reuven@gmail.com',
                      'Phone': '0504445588',
                      'IsTemporaryPassword': false,
                      'IsActive': true,
                      'CreateDate': '2017-06-13T00:00:00',
                      'LastUpdateDate': '2017-06-13T00:00:00'
                    }
                  ],
                  'Messages': []
                }";

            vm = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserViewModel>(json);

            Session.Add("Data", vm);
            ViewBag.jsonData = json;

        }
        else
        {
            vm = (UserViewModel)Session["Data"];
            vm.Users = vm.Users.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
        }
        return vm;

    }
}
```

In the view I coded:

```
@model IEnumerable<UserViewModel>
                    @foreach(var users in Model)
{
    <p>@UserViewModel.json</p>
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you expand a little more on *is not working*? Are you getting an error, it's not showing up correctly, etc?

Comment: @StaticBeagle yes. nothing appears on screen. I am trying also using ajax, and I see on the screen my function without compiling it. Thank you!

Comment: Can the controller code too? What is `UserViewModel.json` ? Static property of `UserViewModel` class?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya no, its not static property of UserViewModel class. I tried to get to var json that hold the data

Comment: You want to display JSON data of `UserViewModel` instance in the view? Can you share the controller code which passes data to the view and returns the view?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have a controller which inside is "getUsers" I need to connect it to a page (list.cshtml) . I mean, I want to see the details getting from the function "getUsers" (which including Json data) . the UserViewModel including list of users, user is a class including data about the user (id, adress etc)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I can share any code. just the part of  passing data to the view - in this time Json data I don't know how to do.. I am new with MVC.. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your code, but it is not clear that ***GetUsers*** is in controller or in service class, by the way, you add this line

```
ViewBag.jsonData = json;
```

and in your view tries to show json data in a wrong way:

```
@UserViewModel.json
```

add this line yo your view so you can see json value:

```
<p>@ViewBag.jsonData</p>
```